# Using ServiceTasks with TimerCatchingEvents in activiti bpmn workflow behaving inconsistently

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

When using ServiceTasks with IntermediateTimerEvents sometimes it did not execute the service task due to exception raised in ACT_RU_JOB table.  EXCEPTION_MSG_ column in ACT_RU_JOB table is populated with *Unknown property used in expression: #{serviceTask1.execute(execution)*. value for that particular job.

Please refer the activiti workflow image i have attached below for clear picture of the usecase.

**NOTE:** I am using spring-boot microservice using maven to run the workflow.

```
  spring-boot version: 1.5.5.RELEASE
  activity version: 5.22.0

 Activity and Connection Pool dependencies in pom.xml:  
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
        <version>${activiti.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  Connection Pooling dependency:
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  application.properties configuration attached below:
  spring.activiti.job-executor-activate=false
  spring.activiti.async-executor-enabled=true
  spring.activiti.async-executor-activate=true

  spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=15
  spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=100
```

ANALYSIS: The error i am getting above is not consistent.

[activiti workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWwpR.png)

Project link on Github:
https://github.com/cloudnativeview/spring-activiti-bpmn-kickstart

Comment: Could you attach your BPMN process definition XML file?

Comment: have you made service tasks async?

Comment: @AbbasKararawala: I have not made the Service task async as its not required in my use case. I have a finding i.e when i use intermediate timer event with event based gateway then it is working flawlessly.

Comment: @RokProdan: Unable to add BPMN process definition so i have shared the project link on Github. Please find the link in the question description.

Comment: @cloudnativeview i ran your code multiple times on my machine, no error. anything that you changed?

Answer (score -1):

The exception is totally expected because you don't set the appropriate process variable when starting your process instance. Also Activiti engine is not able to resolve named bean `serviceTask1`.

From the [Activiti 5.22.0 userguide docs](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/releases/tag/activiti-5.22.0) (inside the file activiti-5.22.0.zip), more precisely section **8.5.3. Java Service Task** you have 4 ways of declaring how to invoke Java logic.

- Specifying a class that implements JavaDelegate or ActivityBehavior.
- Evaluating an expression that resolves to a delegation object.
- Invoking a method expression.
- Evaluating a value expression.

In your BPMN process definition file you are invoking service task Java logic with `method expression` technique. If you want to successfully invoke your method you have to make sure your bean `serviceTask1` is a process variable from your execution or a named object in Spring context.

Unfortunately you don't provide necessary information to your BPM engine on where to find your bean with Java logic.

I suggest you the following steps.

1. Read the technical and userguide documentation (chapter 8.5.3. Java Service Task), from the provided links.
2. Try to invoke Java logic with the way of *specifying a class that implements JavaDelegate or ActivityBehavior*. In my humble opinion it is far more easier to get the first touch with Activiti BPM engine.

Comment: Let me clarify one by one.
1) As you mentioned that i have not set the process variable properly to that,
    I have only used one process variable i.e "counter" and before starting the process instance i am passing the same. Please refer ActivitiController where u will find the API details.
2) To your second point, i am using 3 service tasks and for the same i have created 3 classes which extends JavaDelegate and i am also overriding the execute method.
Also in the process definition i am using expression type to invoking the same.

I am not sure which project u r referring.Please check

Comment: Please review it one more time and let me know if u need any additional help.

Comment: I am refering to the project in the link you provided in your question i. e. https://github.com/cloudnativeview/spring-activiti-bpmn-kickstart. What I was trying to say is that you miss something like variableMap.put("serviceTask1", new ServiceTask1()); in your ActivitiController if you invoke your Java logic with method expression. Further I suggested you use activiti:class="com.cloudnativeview.workflows.service.ServiceTask1" instead of  activiti:expression="#{serviceTask1.execute(execution)}". The same applies for all other service tasks from your BPMN process definition XML file.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but there is no need to add serviceTask1 to the variable map as this is a Service Task Class and it has nothing to do with the variable map.
Also as u already mentioned above that invoking a service task can be done in multiple way so i am just using the expression way and u specify the java class name.

Comment: Directly from technical docs of Activiti 5.22.0 (for using method expressions in service tasks) - The named objects (in your case "serviceTask1", "serviceTask2" and "serviceTask3") are resolved in the execution’s process variables and (if applicable) in the Spring context. I was dealing with the same problem. Good luck.

Comment: the impl. is correct upto my knowledge: there is no problem with xml or service code

Comment: @AbbasKararawala: The problem i have explained only occurring very few times and you can only reproduce when u run multiple process instances at once i.e suppose you have 2 or 3 process definitions and you run 4 to 5 process instances at once, then only the problem arise, btw thanks for the update

Comment: @cloudnativeview have you solved the problem and how?

Comment: @AbbasKararawala please I would like to hear your explanation on my comments, why they are not correct? The same thing is written in book Activiti in Action (author Tijs Rademakers), section 4.3.1

Comment: @RokProdan i did added comment after marking your answer not useful :)